# Can I use the place ID to get just the geolocation? - minimise cost in google maps platform

Tags: flutter, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-places-api, google-places-autocomplete

I want to use markers in a map for a start point and endpoint. By searching I found that the way to do that is to use autocomplete, get some suggestions, and based on the place ID of the selected suggestion to return the longitude and latitude of the place by calling the places details API by ID. So I would like to know if there is any better way to avoid using the places details API which is one of the most expensive [Places details table cost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xt8ZA.png). Is there any way to get the just geolocation of a place based on the place ID?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can [use the Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/requests-places-geocoding) (or [the Geocoding Service in the Maps JavaScript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding)) to fetch a place from its Place ID, simply use the `place_id` parameter in the web service, or include (only) the `placeId` field in [the JavaScript request](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#GeocodingRequests). While the Geocoding API returns only a subset of the fields provided by Place Details, it should lower the cost by about 70%.

**However**, when using this approach there will be an **additional cost** for [Place Autocomplete billed by request](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/usage-and-billing#ac-per-request), because the Geocoding API does not support the session token that enables [billing per session](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/usage-and-billing#ac-with-details-session).